# TypeScript Compiler API: How to get parent class name?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to parse some typescript files to generate some specific documentation, and for that I need to find all classes that are children of a specific class.

I tried to use the code proposed here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#using-the-type-checker

But it does not specify the parent class name (or the type)

```
/**
 * Documentation for C
 */
export class C {
    /**
     * constructor documentation
     * @param a my parameter documentation
     * @param b another parameter documentation
     */
    constructor(a: string, b: C) { }
}

export class D extends C{

}
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "C",
        "documentation": "Documentation for C",
        "type": "typeof C",
        "constructors": [
            {
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "a",
                        "documentation": "my parameter documentation",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "b",
                        "documentation": "another parameter documentation",
                        "type": "C"
                    }
                ],
                "returnType": "C",
                "documentation": "constructor documentation"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "D",
        "documentation": "",
        "type": "typeof D",
        "constructors": [
            {
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "a",
                        "documentation": "my parameter documentation",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "b",
                        "documentation": "another parameter documentation",
                        "type": "C"
                    }
                ],
                "returnType": "D",
                "documentation": "constructor documentation"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But I would like to have something like this :

```
[
    /** C declaration **/
    {
        "name": "D",
        "documentation": "",
        "type": "C", // because extends C
        "parent": "C", // Or like this 
        "constructors": [
            {
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "a",
                        "documentation": "my parameter documentation",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "b",
                        "documentation": "another parameter documentation",
                        "type": "C"
                    }
                ],
                "returnType": "D",
                "documentation": "constructor documentation"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried to find documentation on parsing typescript. If anyone has any link or ideas it will be really appreciable!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function for retrieving the fully qualified name of the parent class that could be plugged in to generate the "parent" value (tested with version 3.9.5):

```
function getParentClassFQName(node: ts.ClassDeclaration, checker: ts.TypeChecker): string | undefined {

    if (!node.heritageClauses) {
        return;
    }

    for (let clause of node.heritageClauses) {
        if (clause.token == ts.SyntaxKind.ExtendsKeyword) {
            if (clause.types.length != 1) {
                console.warn('error parsing extends expression "'+clause.getText()+'"');
            } else {
                let symbol = checker.getSymbolAtLocation(clause.types[0].expression);
                if (!symbol) {
                    console.warn('error retrieving symbol for extends expression "'+clause.getText()+'"');
                } else {
                    return checker.getFullyQualifiedName(symbol);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

where `checker=program.getTypeChecker()` and node is such a node that passes `ts.isClassDeclaration(node)` check.

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions here are perfect - one doesn't return the right answer and one is overly complex.

Try this:

```
classType.getBaseTypes()
```

It returns an array of base types. I actually don't understand how you could possibly have more than one, so you might want to check for that case and throw an error, so you know if it happens:

```
const getBaseType = (classType) => {
  const baseTypes = classType.getBaseTypes() ?? []

  if (baseTypes.length === 0) {
      throw new Error("No base types.")
  }

  if (baseTypes.length > 1) {
      throw new Error("> 1 base types; not sure which one to pick!")
  }

  return baseTypes[0];
}
```

And if you need to get the type of the class, try something like

```
const classType = program.getTypeChecker().getTypeAtLocation(classNode)
```

Comment: You cannot have more than one result when you `extend` a class or interface but you can have multiple results when you `implement` other types.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler API's `TypeChecker` offers a method called [`getBaseTypeOfLiteralType`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/ee25cdecbca49b2b5a290ecd65224f425b1d6a9c/lib/typescript.d.ts#L1871). The return value is a [`Type`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/ee25cdecbca49b2b5a290ecd65224f425b1d6a9c/lib/typescript.d.ts#L2198-L2204) object, which contains `symbol: Symbol`. The [symbol](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/ee25cdecbca49b2b5a290ecd65224f425b1d6a9c/lib/typescript.d.ts#L2092-L2100) in turn contains `escapedName`:

```
checker.getBaseTypeOfLiteralType(constructorType).symbol.escapedName
```

You can insert this into the `serializeClass` function of the code you've used:

```
function serializeClass(symbol: ts.Symbol) {
    ...
    (<any>details).baseType = checker.getBaseTypeOfLiteralType(constructorType).symbol.escapedName;
    return details;
}
```

This should give you output like this:

```
{
    name: 'D',
    type: 'typeof D',
    constructors: [ ... ],
    baseType: 'C'
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but the baseType returned is still "D". I continue to investigate ... if any other ideas ...